# I need help on using an array made in one class in a different class and get its sum

Tags: c#, arrays

In my Inputs class I have an array named score. I need to use it in my MathFun class and get the sum of it.

```
class Inputs

{
    int amountgames;
    public void AmountOfGames()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many games did you play?");
        amountgames = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public void Scores()
    {
        int[] score = new int[amountgames];

        Console.WriteLine("score for game ");
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
        {
            score[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe scores you entered are");
        for (int j = 0; j < score.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(score[j]);
        }
    } 
}

class MathFun
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int total;
    int averaged; 
    public int Average;
    public int Added1;

    public MathFun()
    {
    }

    public void DivideThem()
    {
        Average = number1 / number2;
    }
    public void Added()
    {
        Added1 = inputs.score.sum();
        //This is where in the array and its sum
    }

    public MathFun(int innumber1, int innumber2)
    {
        number1 = innumber1;
        number2 = innumber2;
    }
    public int Number1
    {
        get
        {
            return number1;
        }
        set
        {
            number1 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Number2
    {
        get
        {
            return number2;
        }
        set
        {
            number2 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            return total;
        }

    }
    public int Averaged
    {
        get
        {
            return averaged;
        }
    }
    public void CalcTotal()
    {

        total = Added1;
        averaged = Average;
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary said to much code add more details and there isn't much more i can think to add

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

- Create an instance of Inputs that you can use in MathFun.
- Make Scores() static, so that an instance is not required.  If you do that, amountgames and AmountOfGames() will also have to become static.
- Either way, you will have to return the inputs from Scores() or store them in some way in the class.

  public int[] Scores()
      {
      int[] score = new int[amountgames];

  ```
  Console.WriteLine("score for game ");
  for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
  {
  score[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  Console.WriteLine("\nThe scores you entered are");
   for (int j = 0; j < score.Length; j++)
      {
  Console.WriteLine(score[j]);
      }
  } 
  return score;
  ```

  }

Here's how you could approach it with the first approach

```
Inputs inputs = new Inputs();
int[] scores = Scores();
// Use scores with MathFun
```

*NOTE: I would not generally create a function that is both responsible for writing scores out to the console and returning them.  A single responsibility per method is preferred.  The solution here is one that modifies your current code as little as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution

```
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
 {
     sum += score[i];
 }
```

add this to the array to add it all up
then just make an instance of sum